# iOS Webapp. Swipe back is not working in standalone mode

Tags: ios, safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, iphone-web-app, ios-standalone-mode

I have put the meta tags in my html header to transform my site into an fullscreen webapp. Everything is working fine, without the known swipe back gestures from safari.

Does anyone know why its not working and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This gesture is not supported in full screen web apps. I suggest adding the appropriate UI to your web application so that the user can navigate without it. Hopefully this is something that gets added in the future.